# How to solve this question without doing trial and error?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

$a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive numbers.

$a.b = 15$

$b.c = 18$

- What is the minimum value of $a+b+c$?

So, I want to solve this question without doing trial and error. What is the other way to solve it?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods.

$ab = 15; a=\frac {15}b$.  $bc = 18; c=\frac {18}b$.  So $a + b +c = \frac {15}b + b + \frac {18}b$

1) by AM-GM if $a,b,c$ are positive: $ \frac {15}b + b + \frac {18}b = \frac {33}b + b \ge 2\sqrt{\frac {33}b*b} = 2\sqrt{33} \approx 11.489125293076057319701222936438$

This occurs with $\frac {33}b = b$ or when $b^2 = 33$ and $b=\sqrt{33}$

2) Let $f(b) =  \frac {15}b + b + \frac {18}b = \frac {33}b + b $

$f'(b) = -\frac {33}{b^2}+1$

$f'(b) = 0 \implies \frac {33}{b^2} = 1\implies b=\pm \sqrt{33}$

$f''(b) = 2\frac {33}{b^3}$.  $f(-\sqrt{33}) < 0$ so $b=-\sqrt{33}$ is a local maximum.  $f(\sqrt{33})<0$ so $b= \sqrt{33}$ is a local minimum.

We are given $b$ is positive.

[Big picture: $b= 0$ is a vertical asymptote.  For $b < 0$ $f(b) < 0$ with a max at $b=-\sqrt{33}$. For $b > 0$ $f(b) > 0$ with a min at $b=\sqrt{33}$]

So the minimum value is $f(\sqrt{33})=\frac {33}{\sqrt{33}} + \sqrt{33}= 2\sqrt{33}$.

If it is a requirement that $a,b,c$ by integers then as $f(b)$ is continuous and we have $5 < sqrt{33} < 6$ that $b$ must be the closest common divisor of $15$ and $18$ to $b$.  As the common divisors are $1$ and $3$ then closest is (not very close) $3$ so $b=3$, and $a= 5$ and $c = 6$ so $a + b + c = 14$.

But we can find closer non-integers.  If $b=5$  ($3<5<\sqrt{33}$) we can have $a= 3$ and $c = 3\frac 35$ and $a + b + c= 11 \frac 35$.  If $b=6$ then $a = 2\frac 12$ and $a+b+c = 11 \frac 12$.

But the absolute smallest is $b = \sqrt{33}$ and $a = \frac {15}{\sqrt{33}}$ and $c = \frac {18}{\sqrt{33}}$ and $a + b +c = 
\frac {15}{\sqrt{33}}+\sqrt{33} + \frac {18}{\sqrt{33}} = 2\sqrt{33} \approx 11.489125293076057319701222936438$

Answer (score 0):

from the conditions we obtain $$a=\frac{24}{b},c=\frac{3}{b}$$ so we get
$$a+b+c=\frac{24}{b}+b+\frac{3}{b}$$ now you can differentiate this with respect to $b$
and we get $$6\sqrt{6}$$ as the searched minimum for $b=3\sqrt{6}$

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting integer numbers.

Comment: solve the equation $$-\frac{24}{b^2}+1-\frac{3}{b^2}=0$$ for $b$

Comment: Have you gotten any integer less than $\frac {9}{2\sqrt{3}} + 6\sqrt 6$?

Comment: @fleablood No, I've gotten $14$ for $a+b+c$.

Comment: we can read above positve numbers, not integers

Comment: However, I want to find the minimum value of $a + b + c$. Not $a$, $b$ or $c$ because It seems a bit hard to me. Also is $b$ $54$?

Comment: under the conditions $$ab=24$$ and $$bc=30$$

Comment: I had updated my question. I had written them wrong. $ab = 15$ and $cb = 18$ By the way, maybe we get wrong answer. That's why I did not get your answer.

Comment: Could you edit it?

Comment: $\frac {24}{3\sqrt 6} + 3\sqrt{6} + \frac {3}{3\sqrt 6} \approx 11.02 < 14$.  But $14$ is likely the closest with $a,b,c$ being integers.

Comment: @fleablood you are too right but I wrote the question wrong. It must be $ab = 15$ and $cb = 18$.